# return url post to PayPal will override the return url that has already set in the paypal merchant account

Tags: php, paypal

I have already set the return url in my paypal merchant account

PayPal merchant account-->profile-->Selling Preferences-->Website Payment Preferences-->Auto Return for Website Payments turn radio button to on.

Then i set the reurn url there.

In my php code,i post the 'return' variable  with a url to paypal .Then  will it override the existing return url that i already set in merchant account ?

Let me know one more thing,I can't able to set the return url in my sandbox merchant account in the same way that i did in my live account.How can i set it in sand box account, so that i can test it

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get there in the Sandbox. The section may be called "Website payments preferences" and be found under the "Hosted payment settings" category.

Here is a direct URL to the page, make sure you're signed into your Sandbox Seller account before you open this:
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-website-payments